# syntax highlighting error using styled components in nextjs

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, next.js, styled-components

I am having some trouble with the styled-components vscode extension. When i try to use props within a styled component the arrow function highlighting isn't correct I've tried other themes but to no avail. Is there anything i need to do different?

[image]